# What process number should I put in my supervisor config file?

Tags: linux, supervisord

So how many processes should I run at the same time for a project in my supervisor config file under `numprocs`?

And what are the advantages of having multiple ones running at the same time? Wouldn't it be faster if there was just 1 process?

Answer (score 6):

`numprocs` [controls](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html) how many processes supervisord will run at the same time.  If you just want to run a simple program, you'd leave this unset; the default is 1.

This setting would be useful if you have a server process which needs many copies running as the targets of a load balancer, for example.  Or if you have a program which can run one instance per CPU core to do some work in parallel.  But most programs wouldn't fit this description.

Comment: I just have a website, that is doing a few image manipulations to uploaded files and that manipulation bit is done through queues. There can be many simultaneous manipulations to be done, as users register and upload their photos..

Comment: Error: %(process_num) must be present within process_name when numprocs > 1 in section 'program:

So no, it needs to be there